# Get all records with left join even there's no record on table B

Tags: mysql

I have some problems with this SQL Query, I have 2 tables:

cliente:

```
id  |     dni     | Nombre
1   | 10296450823 | John Doe
2   | 10296780893 | Mark Doe
```

deuda

```
id | monto_deuda | id_cliente
1  | 125.00      | 1
1  | 125.00      | 1
```

But When I run this query:

```
SELECT dni AS Identidad, SUM(de.monto_deuda) as deuda FROM cliente LEFT JOIN deudas de ON de.id_cliente = cliente.id
```

I recive this result:

[MySQL Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsQHi.png)

You can see, I only get the customer with id 1, but I don't receive the other customer that not have any register on table "deuda".

I want to get ALL customers, even if they do not have any record on "deuda" table

How I can do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group your data to get a `sum()` for each group and not the complete result

```
SELECT dni AS Identidad, 
       SUM(de.monto_deuda) as deuda 
FROM cliente 
LEFT JOIN deudas de ON de.id_cliente = cliente.id
GROUP BY dni
```